# Interpreting Python code for partial derivatives of multi-variable function

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand how the following code works to numerically approximate the partial derivative of a function of multiple variables. To quote the book:

> When f is a function of many variables, it has multiple partial derivatives, each indicating how f changes when we make small changes in just one of the input variables.
>   We calculate its ith partial derivative by treating it as a function of just its ith variable,
>   holding the other variables fixed:

```
def partial_difference_quotient(f, v, i, h):
    """compute the ith partial difference quotient of f at v"""
    w = [v_j + (h if j == i else 0) for j, v_j in enumerate(v)] # add h to just the ith element of v

    return (f(w) - f(v)) / h

def estimate_gradient(f, v, h=0.00001):
    return [partial_difference_quotient(f, v, i, h) for i, _ in enumerate(v)]
```

Unfortunately, the books doesn't give any example of how to use the code; it just states that this will give you the partial derivative and then moves on.

The first thing I did is to try to rewrite the code so that it is more readable for someone with my background (I'm more used to seeing C++ code), but I'm not sure if I've done it right.

```
def partial_difference_quotient1(f, v, i, h):   # i is the variable that this function is being differentiated with respect to
    w = []
    for j, v_j in enumerate(v):
        if i == j:      # add h to just the ith element of v
            w.append(v_j + h)
        else:
            w.append(v_j)

    return (f(w) - f(v)) / h

def estimate_gradient1(f, v, h=0.00001):
    list1 = []
    for i, _ in enumerate(v):
        list1.append(partial_difference_quotient1(f, v, i, h))

    return list1
```

If the code is correct, then I'm still not sure how to use it. For instance, let's say I would like to find the partial derivative of f = x^2 + x*y^2 at y = 3, then I tried

```
def f1(x, y):
    return (x*x) + (x*y*y)

v = range(-10,10)
f = partial(f1, y=3)
f_x = estimate_gradient1(f, v, h=0.00001)
```

I can see that this wouldn't work because, for isntance, you can't multiply a list (i.e. v) with itself (x*x in the function f1). But it is clear from the code that v should be a list, so I've how to use the code.

Comment: That code doesn't work, there are comments in the middle of it : p

Comment: Could you write the `d/dx` equation in mathematical terms please? I find it difficult to follow your code. It's written in C style, but Python code; as you've pointed out yourself.

Comment: `for i, _ in enumerate(v)` is a pattern I've never seen before. Usually people write `for i in range(len(v))`, or sometimes `xrange` in Python 2.

Comment: `for i, __ in enumerate(v)` means that take the row number and discard the value during the iteration. `enumerate` is faster and more logical in `for` loops. Using `range(len(x))` is considered a bad practice in Python, as `for` loops are meant to be iterating through an array/list whose items are used within the loop, and not merely as iterating loops that conduct repeating performances.

Comment: this book seems really interesting,  could you tell me its title  ? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to use it:

```
def f(v):
    x, y = v
    return (x*x) + (x*y*y)

x = 3
y = 3
v = [x, y]
grad = estimate_gradient1(f, v, h=0.00001)
print(grad)
```

This outputs:

```
[15.000009999965867, 18.000030000564493]
```

which is approximately correct.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you can work out the partial of a vector, you can do this:

For `d/dx x^2+2x+1`, the easiest way is to simply calculate the gradient for `y` in terms of an array of `x`:

```
from numpy import arange, gradient

x = arange(0, 50, 0.01)  # Range

y = ((x**2) + (2*x)) + 1  # Function

ddx = gradient(y)  # Gradient
```

which yields the following:
[image: Plot of <code>f(x)</code> and its gradient.]

Another arbitrary example of `dx/dt`, `d2/dy2`, and phase plot would be as follows:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from numpy import arange, sin, cos, gradient


def sdot(y, t, *args):
    val = sin(t*2)+(sin(y**(t/4)))
    return val

init = 0
x = arange(0, 30, 0.01)

args = (None)

dydt = odeint(sdot, y0=init, t=x, args=(args,))
d2dy2 = gradient(dydt[:, 0])
```

[image: Plot of <code>f(x)</code>, its gradient, and its phase plot.]

For additional information of `gradient`, see the documentations [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html), and for `odeint` see [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html). Also, you may find some additional information on [vectorisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_programming) (aka. array programming) useful too.

For actual partial derivatives (i.e. through integration), you may also do this:

```
from scipy.misc import derivative

def partial_derivative(func, var=0, point=[]):
    args = point[:]
    def wraps(x):
        args[var] = x
        return func(*args)
    return derivative(wraps, point[var], dx = 1e-6)
```

Although this would be rather more challenging for someone who is not a hardcore (Python) programmer. But if you're keen to learn it, you can find the documentations [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.derivative.html); and learn more about wrappers and decorators in this nice tutorial from the Code Ship in [here](http://thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/).

Hope this gives you an idea of how you can handle derivatives in Python.

Comment: The title of the question starts with "Interpreting Python code". OP is not simply asking how to calculate partial derivatives in general, but how to use and understand the functions in the question and how numerical methods are programmed.

Comment: And I have attempted to give a complete introduction to integration in Python, which serves as (a) a learning material, (b) an example of how to interpret and write functions in Python for mathematical purposes (including how numerical methods are programmed in Python through vectorisation, rather than repetitive iterations). S/he is clearly having problems in terms of handling arrays in Python, and until that is clear, any other answer for just be confusing / a quick fix. That's my personal opinion of course, and you're welcome to object.

Comment: Thank you, very interesting information which I will need later, but I want to get more comfortable with Python first